# How to properly calculate band math using ImageMath?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I would like to perform some simple band math on an RGB image. I'd like the output to be `green/(red+green+blue)`.

This is what I've tried, but it produces a black image: Individual bands were produced by splitting the original RGB image into red, green and blue.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageMath
 
im = Image.open(r"SYFW0142.JPG")

im1 = Image.Image.split(im)
red = im1[0]
green = im1[1]
blue = im1[2]

out = ImageMath.eval("green/(red+green+blue)", red=red, green=green, blue=blue)
```

The `red` image:

[image: red band]

The `green` image:

[image: green band]

The `blue` image:

[image: blue band]

The `out` image:

[image: output band]

---

**Edit:** I've realised that this math will produce values between 0 and 1. However, even when multiplying the equation by 255, I still get a black image...

Comment: Could be the correct  output. Try posting the input image to try to get more informative answers from people that now pillow better than me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noticed yourself, you're generating values in the range of `[0.0 ... 1.0]`. Furthermore, looking at the three channels, and since your result is all black, it seems, that the following holds for every pixel:

```
g / (r + g + b) < 0.5
```

So, now, you haven't shown the code mentioned in your edit, i.e. the multiplying by `255`, but I assume you did something like this:

```py
out = ImageMath.eval("green/(red+green+blue)*255", red=red, green=green, blue=blue)
```

Unfortunately, the expression `green/(red+green+blue)` is still fully calculated before multiplying with `255`, so you (still) have `0 * 255 = 0` for every pixel. Put the multiplication to the front, like so:

```py
out = ImageMath.eval("255*green/(red+green+blue)", red=red, green=green, blue=blue)
```

It's save to do that, since [all operations are done with 32-bit integers](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageMath.html#standard-operators).

Here's some code snippet:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageMath

im = Image.open('path/to/your/image.png')
red, green, blue = Image.Image.split(im)

# Original calculation #1 - wrong result
out = ImageMath.eval("green/(red+green+blue)", red=red, green=green, blue=blue)
print(out.getpixel((0, 0)))
# 0

# Original calculation #2 - still wrong result
out = ImageMath.eval("green/(red+green+blue)*255", red=red, green=green, blue=blue)
print(out.getpixel((0, 0)))
# 0

# Multiplication at the front - right result
out = ImageMath.eval("255*green/(red+green+blue)", red=red, green=green, blue=blue)
print(out.getpixel((0, 0)))
# 85
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```